# Is there any group $H\times K$ where $H\times 1$ and $1\times K$ are the only subgroups of order $n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

$G=H\times K$ where $H$ and $K$ are non-isomorphic groups of order $n$.

I am looking for an example such that $G$ has no subgroup of order $n$ except $H\times 1$ and $1\times K$.

If anyone can find such a group, I would be thankful.

**Edit:** Let $G$ be such an example, then $H\times 1$ and $1\times K$ must be characteristic group in $G$ which means $\operatorname{Aut}(G)\cong \operatorname{Aut}(H)\times \operatorname{Aut}(K)$ and clearly $(|H|,|K|)\neq 1$. This may make question easy.(to reach contradiction)

Comment: Scratch my previous comment. I read the details of the question wrong.

Comment: @John: please notice that $|H|=|K|=n$

Comment: So this cannot happen if $H$ and $K$ are both solvable, since then there are several ways of constructing subgroups of the given order. I need to think a bit more on what happens in general.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: yes and if one of them is $p$ seperable, then it is still not possible.

Comment: Yeah, that is a quite big generalization of my comment.

Comment: Hmm, so if we have a subgroup of te direct product given by a $5$-tuple in the usual way, what will the order of this be, given the orders of the subgroups in the tuple?

Comment: @spin I don't quite see how you get that conclusion. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @spin: I am not sure but, there is little problem in your last argument. Let $\bar R$ be image of $R$ and $\bar R$ is a subgroup of $H/N \times K/M$ with order $n/t$ which is not $H/N \times 1$ and $1 \times K/M $, how can you conclude that order of the $R$ is $n$.

Comment: Neither A8 x L34 nor PSp63 x O73 work.

Comment: @mesel: You are right, there is a problem. The order would be $nt$.. so that argument doesn't work. I deleted my comment

Comment: This is an interesting question. Can I ask where you got the motivation for the problem?

Comment: I am  trying to minimize the number of the subgroup with given order. I tried my chance in direct product.

Comment: Best place to look would be the $\text{Sp}$ and $\text{O}$ simple groups. But I don't know enough about them to proceed.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber: I guess we need to use GAP program  but I do not know how to use it.

Comment: @mesel: direct products have an enormous number of subgroups of the same order, so this would probably be one of the hardest cases.

Comment: @JackSchmidt:  Yeah, but it has a relation with my main case, If you are intereseted, I can send you the main problem.

Comment: One trivial observation: The Sylow $p$-subgrops of $H$ and $K$ are isomorphic?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: the sylows would not typically be isomorphic. For instance in A8 x L34 we have A8 and L34 are characteristic of the same order, but with non-isomorphic Sylow 2-subgroups.

Comment: @mesel: I think the problem is still very hard. We know $H \neq K$ (and that they have no common direct factors), but to make them characteristic all we need is for there to be no homomorphism from H to Z(K) and none from K to Z(H). So any two distinct perfect groups of the same order are conceivable. I doubt any such example exists (large groups have a large number of subgroups), but I don't see how to prove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is answered in [this MathOverflow thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/161701/finite-groups-g-so-that-g-has-exactly-two-subgroups-of-a-given-order).

There is an example in a 2002 paper of Guralnick (*Groups with exactly two subgroups of a given order*, Communications in Algebra, Vol. 30, No. 9, pp. 4401-4406), but it seems as though it was an open problem until then.